# Regular Expression for replacing XML Tag

Tags: php, xml, regex, parsing

I am trying to replace a tag from a xml. I have stored a xml results through curl in variable. and trying to make a file.xml.
when it

```
  <Topics>
  <Topic code="Balances" count="26" pagesize="100" />
  </Topics>
```

with this function , it doesnt return any matches. why?

```
 function get_tag( $tag, $xml ) {
    $tag = preg_quote($tag);

     preg_match_all('{<'.$tag.'[^>]*>(.*?)</'.$tag.'>}',
               $xml,
               $matches,
               PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  return $matches[1];
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is a very poor and slow implementation of parsing a document. Suggestively you should have a look at the `DOMDocument` object and try to implement it.

Basic usage according to your example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML("<xml ... />"); // Current document

$replace = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag);

foreach ($replace as $node)
{
    $xml = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $xml->loadXML("<xml ... />"); // XML to replace original with

    $dom->replaceChild($xml, $node); // XML is your new node
}

$dom->normalize(); // Saves the changes
echo $dom->saveXML(); // Output
```

Edit; Sorry - better example now.

Comment: +1 Daniel is right. It is highly inadvisable to parse XML with regular expressions.

Comment: You cannot use loadXML on a DocumentFragment.
The line:
`$xml->loadXML("<xml ... />"); // XML to replace original with`
can be replaced with:
`$xml->appendXML("<xml ... />"); // XML to replace original with`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
<?php

$xml = '
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        x
    </tag2>
    <tag3>
    </tag3>
    <tag2>
        y
    </tag2>
</tag1>
';

function get_tag($tag, $xml){
    $tag = preg_quote($tag);

    preg_match_all('/<'.$tag.'.*?>(.*?)<\/'.$tag.'>/s', $xml, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    return $matches[1];
}

print_r(get_tag('tag2', $xml));

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
        x

    [1] => 
        y

)
```